# Is messagebox font size tied to the screen of system the program is coded in?

Tags: .net, windows

I'm writing a program currently on a computer with a 1920x1080 screen and have scaled it so that it will look good for different screen resolutions (as this program may be run on different screens eg. on a laptop). However, I'm only able to test it currently on my current computer and the messagebox doesn't change to match the screen resolution I've changed it to. I understand it's because this uses the default system settings to configure the font size.

If I were to run this software on a different sized screen, would the messagebox adjust the font size for that screen or use the same size as for the system it was coded on?

Comment: *"have scaled it"* - how? Probably you want to scale messageboxes too. Means do it same way as you did with program, e.g. by writing custom modal dialog and applying same things to it.

Comment: If you really require explicit fine-grained control of the `MessageBox`, you will have to implement your own version, with its own custom logic.

Comment: My question is more "will I need to?" than "how do I do it?" in this instance. If, for example, I run it on a screen where the dimensions are smaller than this one, would the messagebox be at the default for *that* screen or at my one? I don't really want to write a custom modal dialog if I don't need to implement anything extra at all.